# Trouble Implementing Zod Validation in Nest.js Application

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I'm encountering an issue with Zod validation in my Nest.js application. I've defined a Zod schema for validating my DTOs, but it seems that the validation is not working as expected. When I send requests with invalid data, the server still accepts them instead of rejecting them based on the validation rules.

```
import { createZodDto } from 'nestjs-zod';
import { z } from 'nestjs-zod/z';

const foldervalidationlayer = z.object({
  Name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: 'Name must be at least 2 characters long.' })
    .max(50, { message: 'Name must be at most 50 characters long.' })
});
export class createFolderDTOlayer extends createZodDto(foldervalidationlayer) {}  `
`Controller 

 @Post('/AddFolder')
  async create(@Body() createFolderDto: createFolderDTOlayer): Promise<createFolderDTOlayer> {
    return this.folderService.create(createFolderDto);
  }
repo 
  async create(newfolder: createFolderDTOlayer): Promise<createFolderDTOlayer> {
    const createFolder = new this.folderModel(newfolder);
    const savedFolder = await createFolder.save();
    return savedFolder;
  }
service 
 async create(createFolderDto: createFolderDTOlayer): Promise<createFolderDTOlayer> {
    return this.folderRepositroy.create(createFolderDto);
  }
schema 
export type Fole = Folder & Document;

@Schema()
export class Folder {
  @Prop({ unique: true, required: true })
  Name: string;
}
export const Folder = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Folder);
```

Comment: How do you bind the validation pipe?